# How to store and index several billion logs every day

Tags: database, indexing, nosql, scalability

Several times we get into situation where we have no logs about request that failed for some customer. We hear from leads that our **service handles billions of request** every day and we **cannot afford to log every request response** for **storage and Network IO performance reasons**. Please share some pointers on any system that could ingest this scale of logs and allow search in near real time.

In short : How do we log request-response logs for 10 billion requests per day and flexibility to search last N days data

Comment: Could you specify your stack/platform?

Comment: We are on cloud so till now we have been logging only small % of requests to save on IO and performance of VM. For this small set we use opentsdb collectors. Going forward we need to log all requests that would be more than 1 billion a day

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Elasticsearch tech. It works with pretty much anything and is has great design for logging.